# Can't resolve "Unrecognized selector sent to instance" error

Tags: objective-c, segue, nib, unrecognized-selector, ios7.1

I read on other stack overflow posts that this error is cause due to improper memory management but I cant figure out where that problem is being caused. I am receiving the following error:

[image: Debug Image]

```
2014-03-23 12:47:16.337 Cazenovia High School[11810:60b] -[iPhoneFirstPageView Twitter]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10944bc10
2014-03-23 12:47:16.342 Cazenovia High School[11810:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[iPhoneFirstPageView Twitter]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10944bc10'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010194c495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001016ab99e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001019dd65d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010193dd8d ___forwarding___ + 973
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010193d938 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000100259f06 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 80
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000100259eb4 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 17
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000100336880 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 203
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000100335dc0 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 530
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010057d6f7 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 5149
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000100290a15 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 928
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001002916d4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 909
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010026929a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 211
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000100256aed _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 9579
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001018dbd21 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001018db5f2 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001018f746f __CFRunLoopRun + 767
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001018f6d83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000103ac3f04 GSEventRunModal + 161
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000100258e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    20  Cazenovia High School               0x0000000100002ef3 main + 115
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000101fe45fd start + 1
    22  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

My code is included below, you can also find my project on http://github.com/rileylloyd24/cazenovia

I have a ScrollView in my Storyboard (ViewController) with an embedded nav controller (navigationController). I also have 2 nibs, one of which (iPhoneFirstPageView) I am trying to segue to another nib (TwitterViewController).

ViewController.h

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TwitterViewController.h"
#import "iPhoneFirstPageView.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Set up View for scrollview with nav controller
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
    self.title = @"Cazenovia Central School District";
    self.bottomBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:9.0f/255.0f green:49.0f/255.0f blue:102.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    //do some set up on the scrollview
    self.theScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.theScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.theScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

    //Load the nibs to be paged through
    //NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"iphoneFirstPageView" owner:self options:nil];
    //UIView *firstPageView = (UIView *)[nibArray objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"iphoneFirstPageView" owner:self options:nil];
    iPhoneFirstPageView *firstPageView = (iPhoneFirstPageView *)[nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
    [firstPageView.twitterButton addTarget:self action:@selector(executeSegue) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    NSArray *nibArray2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"iPhoneSecondPage" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *secondPageView = (UIView *)[nibArray2 objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *pageArray = @[firstPageView, secondPageView];

    //Add each view to the scroll view
    for(int i=0; i<pageArray.count; i++){
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.theScrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.theScrollView.frame.size;

        UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [subview addSubview:[pageArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        [self.theScrollView addSubview:subview];
    }
    self.theScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.theScrollView.frame.size.width * pageArray.count, self.theScrollView.frame.size.height);
    self.theScrollView.delegate = self;
    self.thePageControl.numberOfPages = pageArray.count;
    //Twitter segue
}


-(void)executeSegue
{
    TwitterViewController *newController = [[TwitterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TwitterViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newController animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.theScrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((self.theScrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    self.thePageControl.currentPage = page;
}
```

Comment: Where does the error occur and what does the deb udder dhow as values of variables there

Comment: @Mark Updated error code above.

Comment: I meant which line in the code

Comment: @Mark Sorry for my incompetence, but I'm not sure how to find that, I included an image of my debugger image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked your code and you need to remove the outlet in story board from twitter icon button.You connected that previously. You have commented previous outlet method `-(IBAction)Twitter` but you also need to remove touchupinside action outlet from storyboard.Just go `iphoneFirstPageView.xib` and right click on twitter button and remove action outlet for Twitter.

For another problem  in `-(void)executeSegue`

You are loading whole viewcontroller from xib so use  `TwitterViewController *newController = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]  loadNibNamed:@"TwitterViewController" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];` instead of `initWithNibName`  and remove the fileowner outlet for view.Then Everything will work fine.

Comment: I removed the touchupinside action, but I need to keep the outlet for the following code in my ViewController.m: [firstPageView.twitterButton addTarget:self action:@selector(executeSegue) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: you did not remove that just remove the action method outlet not property outlet.When you tap the button it will call `executeSegue` method

Comment: I deleted the action and I still get an error, but its a different error "A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time!" <UIView: 0x10950b590; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x109506250>> is associated with <TwitterViewController: 0x10954c7c0>. Clear this association before associating this view with <TwitterViewController: 0x109322130> Any Ideas?

Comment: @iOSNoob see edited answer and accept if it resolved your problem.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!! You just solved an issue I've been battling for many weeks, thanks again for your persistent help.

Comment: @iOSNoob Welcome! I need to add one more point do not use xib's for loading view controllers if you are using storyboard unless you have specific reason for it.Use soryboard for view controller and use xib's for only views.